# a* algorithm pseudocode

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-algorithm, a-star

I am trying to implement in c the pseudocode of a* algorithm given by wikipedia but I am really stuck in understanding what is the reconstruct_path function, can someone explain to me what do the variables in this function (p, p+current_node, set) represent?

```
function A*(start,goal)
 closedset := the empty set    // The set of nodes already evaluated.
 openset := {start}    // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated, initially containing the start node
 came_from := the empty map    // The map of navigated nodes.

 g_score[start] := 0    // Cost from start along best known path.
 // Estimated total cost from start to goal through y.
 f_score[start] := g_score[start] + heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

 while openset is not empty
     current := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
     if current = goal
         return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)

     remove current from openset
     add current to closedset
     for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)
         tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + dist_between(current,neighbor)
         if neighbor in closedset
             if tentative_g_score >= g_score[neighbor]
                 continue

         if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor] 
             came_from[neighbor] := current
             g_score[neighbor] := tentative_g_score
             f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
             if neighbor not in openset
                 add neighbor to openset

 return failure

function reconstruct_path(came_from, current_node)
 if came_from[current_node] in set
     p := reconstruct_path(came_from, came_from[current_node])
     return (p + current_node)
 else
     return current_node
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`came_from` is a map of navigated nodes, like the comment says. It can be implemented in several ways, but a classic map should be fine for this purpose(even a list is fine).

If you are not familiar with maps, checkout [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

The goal of `A*` is to find a list of moves, that will solve the given problem (represented as a graph). A solution is a path through the graph.

In the pseudocode proposed, `came_from` store the "history" of the solution you are actually evaluating (so a possible path through the graph).

When you explore a node (a new node or one with less cost in the already visited list):

```
if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor] 
    came_from[neighbor] := current
```

you are saving in the `came_from` map the node where you come from. (It's simpler to think at it as the ordered list of moves till the solution node is reached. A map is used instead of a list for performance issues).

The line above basically means:

> "Now I'll visit **neighbor** node. Remember that I reached neighbor node
>   coming from **current** node".

When `goal` node is reached, `A*` needs to return the list of moves from `start` node to `goal`. You have the reference to the `goal` node, so you can now recontruct the list(`reconstruct_path`) of moves to reach it coming from `start` node, because you stored the list of moves in `came_from` map.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I have one more question: what is set in the line if came_from[current_node] in set?

Comment: I think it checks the end condition, because it's a recursive function. I think the semantic is "does came_from[current_node] is the last node in the list?"

Comment: thank you, but what list is being referred to: openset or closedset or maybe something else?

Comment: I think it refers to came_from map. Since basically you are iterating back from end to start node in came_from map and build a list of nodes, it tells you when the came_from map has been exhausted

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of nodes and each node in your path can "point" to its predecessor (the node from which you came from to this node) - this is what came_from map is storing .

You want your a* function to return a list* of nodes in the path.

Now, back to `return (p + current_node)` - this code basically means return a list which contains all elements from p with current_node at the end. So it's `p` with 1 element added to the end of `p`.

You can see, that because this function is recursive, at the beginning it will contain a single element - first in your path, which will be a start. You will then add new elements to it, ending with `goal` element at the end.

You could also look at this this way: your algorithm allowed you to find a path from `goal` to `start` (you just need to follow the `came_from` of your nodes). This function allows you to traverse your path from `start` to `goal` thank you recursion, so you should end up with a list of some sort, containing your path in correct order.

* by list I mean some structure that represent a sequence of elements, not a set.